# Automapper UseDestinationValue not working

Tags: c#, automapper

currently struggling with setting of automapper between same classes. The thing is I need to get the entity from db using NHibernate before calling the `SaveOrUpdate()`. I am then replacing all the properties except `Id` and `LocationId`.

**Mapper:**

```
public Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.MeetingRoom MapFrom(Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.MeetingRoom input)
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                lock (Sync)
                {
                    if (!initialized)
                    {
                        Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.MeetingRoom, Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.MeetingRoom>()
                .ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
                .ForMember(x => x.LocationId, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());

                        initialized = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (input == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("MeetingRoom is not set!");
            }

            var result = (Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.MeetingRoom)Mapper.Map(input, input.GetType(), typeof(Domain.DomainObjects.Entities.MeetingRoom));

            return result;
        }
```

**Usage of mapper**

```
using (ITransaction t = NHibernateSession.Current.BeginTransaction())
{
    var m = meetingRoomRepository.FindAll(new MeetingRoomByEmailSpecification(meetingRoom.Email)).FirstOrDefault();

    m = meetingRoomMapper.MapFrom(meetingRoom);

    meetingRoomRepository.SaveOrUpdate(m);

    t.Commit();
}
```

when I am debugging the code I can see that `m` has the `locationId` and `Id` filled but after mapper its being overwriting with the `locationId` and `Id` of the `meetingRoom` (which is 0 by default).

Comment: Why not just ignore them? CreateMap<Foo, Bar>().ForMember(x => x.Blarg, opt => opt.Ignore());

Comment: unfortunately, ignoring doesnt help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the line you're using to map.

```
m = meetingRoomMapper.MapFrom(meetingRoom);
```

you're taking the result of `meetingRoomMapper.MapFrom(meetingRoom)` and assigning it to `m`.  The problem is, that there's no way for `meetingRoomMapper.MapFrom` to even know about the properties of `m`.  You can't expect a line that looks like `m = ...` to not replace the whole object represented by m.

Instead, You should look for a mapping function that takes a destination object as one of it's arguments.

```
m = Mapper.Map(meetingRoom, m);
```

Comment: updated my question with more code. I am already calling the `Mapper.Map(src, dst)` but not sure if in a proper way...

Comment: @pandemic  you need to be able to pass `m` into your `MapFrom` method if you want to keep any of the value on `m`, and then pass `m` into `Mapper.Map()` as the destination object

Comment: secondly, the code you posted does not call a `Mapper.Map(src, dst)`, or more accurately, `Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)`.   It calls `Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType)`

Comment: your last comment has made it clear for me! thanks a lot Sam